# Python Image scraping returning HTML

Tags: python, urllib

I've written a python script to extract image urls from some Javacript and save the image, however, when opening with Preview I get the message

> It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.

Upon closer inspection when opening the `.jpeg` in an editor it seems as though the script is saving the HTML. Where am I going wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as request
import json

folder = r'./gallery'
URL = 'https://web.archive.org/web/20180324152250/http://www.awp.fr:80/project/poissy-galore-museum-visitors-center/'
response = request.urlopen(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

scriptCnt = soup.find('div', {'class': 'posts-wrapper'})
script = scriptCnt.find('script').text

json_str = script[str(script).find('var gallery_items = '):str(script).find(';')].replace('var gallery_items = ', '')
json_str = json.loads(json_str)
for item in json_str:
    print(item['large'])
    filename = item['large'].split('/')[-1]
    req =  request.Request(item['large'],
        headers = {
            'User-agent':
                'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0'})
    resp = request.urlopen(req)
    with open(filename, "wb") as fd:
        fd.write(resp.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `item['large']` is not an image link. I ran your code in a notebook and when I clicked on the link outputted in the notebook, it sent me to another webpage. So you need to go a little bit deeper here. You can modify your loop like this for example:

```
for item in json_str:
    print(item['large'])

    r = request.urlopen(item['large'])
    s = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

    filename = item['large'].split('/')[-1]
    req =  request.Request(s.find('iframe').get('src'),
        headers = {
            'User-agent':
                'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0'})
    resp = request.urlopen(req)
    with open(filename, "wb") as fd:
        fd.write(resp.read())
```